# How do I convert a JavaScript DOM element (and its entire structure) into string (without jQuery)? ..and re-display it on the page as text?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently trying to grab a DOM Element (and its entire sub-elements) and store it as string, so that I could re-display it as plain text on the page.  Similar to this below:

```
// Get DOM Element
var x = document.getElementById("para1");

// Create a new DOM Element and display x as text on the page
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = x;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

I was expecting I would get something like `<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ul>`;  however, what I got instead was `[object HTMLUListElement]`.

Here's the fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/wesosu/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `x.outerHTML` to get the HTML content including the element itself

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = x.outerHTML; // x.innerHTML instead if you only want the contents
document.body.appendChild(div);
```